# Stop a gouroutine after a period of time

Tags: go, concurrency

Is it concurrent safe to Stop a gouroutine after a period of time, like this?

1. [Code](https://play.golang.org/p/8p8j7Anl1Js): (Note: **data race** since `ok` changes in another goroutine):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var ok byte
    time.AfterFunc(1000*time.Millisecond, func() {
        ok = 1
    })

    var i uint64
    for ok == 0 {
        i++ // CPU intensive task
    }
    fmt.Println(i) // 2_776_813_033
}
```

Terminal:

```sh
go run -race .

==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c000132010 by goroutine 8:
  main.main.func1()
      ./main.go:11 +0x46

Previous read at 0x00c000132010 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      ./main.go:15 +0xf4

Goroutine 8 (running) created at:
  time.goFunc()
      go/src/time/sleep.go:180 +0x51
==================
80849692
Found 1 data race(s)
```

---

2. [Code](https://play.golang.org/p/IX0jb2o-Lrj) (**No** data race):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var ok int32
    time.AfterFunc(1000*time.Millisecond, func() {
        atomic.StoreInt32(&ok, 1)
    })

    var i uint64
    for atomic.LoadInt32(&ok) == 0 {
        i++ // CPU intensive task
    }
    fmt.Println(i) // 2_835_935_488
}
```

Terminal:

```sh
go run -race .

31934042
```

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the busy-wait for loop will terminate even if `ok` is set to `false` by another goroutine. There is no explicit synchronization during the setting and reading of `ok`, so the main goroutine is not guaranteed to see the changes made to it. In other words, there is no way to establish a happened-before relationship between the two goroutines.

https://golang.org/ref/mem

Second version of the code is safe even though it is not stated in the Go memory model with respect to `ok`, but it is not safe because such tight loops may not allow other goroutines to execute. Atomic read/write has the memory barriers necessary for a happened-before relationship. You should use one of the synchronization primitives (mutex, channel) to guarantee that.

Comment: Thank you, is there any go spec or any reference on tight loop?

Comment: There is this: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10958 Not a canonical reference, but it explains the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd code is **OK** with Go 1.14+:

[go1.14](https://golang.org/doc/go1.14#runtime)

> Goroutines are now **asynchronously preemptible**. As a result, loops without function calls no longer potentially deadlock the scheduler or significantly delay garbage collection. This is supported on all platforms except windows/arm, darwin/arm, js/wasm, and plan9/*.

---

### Stop a gouroutine after a period of time

```bash
BenchmarkAfterFunc-8            1000000000 0.4468 ns/op  0 B/op  0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDoneChannel-8          121966824   9.855 ns/op  0 B/op  0 allocs/op
BenchmarkTimeSince-8            89790115    12.95 ns/op  0 B/op  0 allocs/op
BenchmarkContextErr-8           58508900    19.78 ns/op  0 B/op  0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAfterFuncMutex-8       58323207    20.00 ns/op  0 B/op  0 allocs/op
BenchmarkContext-8              48947625    27.43 ns/op  0 B/op  0 allocs/op
```

Tests:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

const d = 200 * time.Millisecond //  To stop a task after a period of time

func BenchmarkTimeSince(b *testing.B) {
    t0 := time.Now()
    var count = 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if time.Since(t0) < d {
            count++
        }
    }
    _ = count
}

func BenchmarkContext(b *testing.B) {
    var ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), d)
    defer cancel()
    var count = 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            // break
        default:
            count++
        }
    }
    _ = count
}
func BenchmarkContextErr(b *testing.B) {
    var ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), d)
    defer cancel()
    var count = 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if ctx.Err() == nil {
            count++
        }
    }
    _ = count
}

func BenchmarkAfterFunc(b *testing.B) {
    var done uint32
    time.AfterFunc(d, func() { atomic.StoreUint32(&done, 1) })
    var count = 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if atomic.LoadUint32(&done) == 0 {
            count++
        }
    }
    _ = count
}

func BenchmarkDoneChannel(b *testing.B) {
    var done = make(chan struct{})
    time.AfterFunc(d, func() { close(done) })
    var count = 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        select {
        case <-done:
            // break
        default:
            count++
        }
    }
    _ = count
}

type foo struct {
    sync.Mutex
    state bool
}

func (p *foo) end() {
    p.Lock()
    p.state = true
    p.Unlock()
}
func (p *foo) isDone() bool {
    var b bool
    p.Lock()
    b = p.state
    p.Unlock()
    return b
}
func BenchmarkAfterFuncMutex(b *testing.B) {
    var it = foo{}
    time.AfterFunc(d, func() { it.end() })
    var count = 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if it.isDone() {
            count++
        }
    }
    _ = count
}
```

---

https://medium.com/a-journey-with-go/go-asynchronous-preemption-b5194227371c

> The preemption is an important part of the scheduler that lets it distribute the running time among the goroutines. Indeed, without preemption, a long-running goroutine that hogs the CPU would block the other goroutines from being scheduled. The version 1.14 introduces a new technique of asynchronous preemption, giving more power and control to the scheduler.

See:
[Goroutine preemption](https://go.dev/src/runtime/preempt.go)
[At which point a goroutine can yield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64113394/at-which-point-a-goroutine-can-yield)
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10958
https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/24543-non-cooperative-preemption.md